# Inconsistent UI panel location in 2.8x

Tags: interface

This drives me crazy. One time it is on the top of the screen, the other on the bottom. Why it is not staying at the same place all the time? Is it choosing the location randomly? Is it only my problem?

[image]

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/96527/how-to-ensure-all-headers-are-at-the-top-of-the-editors-every-time   https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/157945/locking-the-viewport-headers-to-a-default-position?r=SearchResults&s=3|26.6852   https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/148036/move-bar-to-bottom-2-8/148037?r=SearchResults&s=7|16.0466#148037

Comment: Oh, ok, thank you!